# RAM access on linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I want to access(read and write) all the RAM(using physical addresses) from Linux kernel(either through user space or kernel space) can we do that? 
what are the possibilities and limitations in userspace?
Up to what extent we can do that using loadable kernel modules?

Thanks and Regards,
Veerendranath

Comment: use `phy_to_virt` to get a virtual address for kernel to access ram. use `/dev/mem` in user space. In kernel space there is no limitation.  In user space, you should have root permission to access `/dev/mem`.

Comment: @Chris Tsui, just a note: In the Linux kernel, if it is needed to write to the memory containing the kernel code or data, one may need to remove the write protection first. [set_memory_rw() function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=4.4;i=set_memory_rw) helps with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to physical address from user space using mmap.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PHY_ADDR 0x807feff

int main()
{
    int i;
    unsigned int *addr;

    int fd = open( "/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC );
    if( fd < 0 )
    {
        perror( "Error opening file /dev/mem" );
        return 1;
    }

    addr = (unsigned int *) mmap( 0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, PHY_ADDR );
    if( addr == NULL )
    {
        perror( "Error mapping" );
        return 1;
    }
    for( i = 0; i < 256 / 4; i++ )
        printf( "addr: %X\tval: %X\n", addr + i, *( addr + i ) );

    if( munmap( addr, getpagesize() ) == -1 )
    {
        perror( "Error unmaping" );
        return 1
    }

    close( fd );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @n.m. for `/dev/mem` device, `mmap` is used to map physical memory to user space.